# Does Aspnet Membership require Full Trust?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm testing my application on the host, and when I try to access a page that tries to read from an Aspnet Membership Profile it returns this message:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Looks like Aspnet Membership is asking to run under full trust, but the hosting provider doesn't allow applications to run under Full Trust. Is there a way to make it work at Medium Trust level?

Comment: Look at this.http://forums.asp.net/t/1422162.aspx/1
Did you put <trust level="Full" /> in your web.config file, inside <system.web> tags?

Comment: I tried to put it on web.config, but my hosting provider doesn't allow applications to run under Full Trust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, looks like Profiles feature in Asp.Net Membership requires Full Trust security level for the application. So, if somebody is trying to host an application that makes use of Asp.Net Membership's Profiles feature, it's a good idea to check if the hosting provider allows applications to run under Full Trust level. Most of them don't (my case). I'll implement a Profile structure by myself.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try using the following from the reference ( http://forums.asp.net/t/1422162.aspx/1)

```
using System;
  namespace ConsoleApplication
  {
     [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

or

<System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted:=True)> _

   class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
               ...
          }  
      }
  }
```

2) If this doesn't helps, try using put `<trust level="Full" />` in your web.config file, inside `<system.web>` tags

3) Run this command `caspol.exe -m -ag LocalIntranet_Zone -url \\<network host>\<share name>\ FullTrust -n FullTrustShare`
(offcourse you need to be login as administrator to execute it)

4) Go to Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Microsoft .NET Framework 
Configuration / configure security settings.
Then to My Computer->Runtime Security Policy node on the left and clicking 
"Adjust Zone Security" link on the right side , give it full trust

Comment: I saw before how to make the application require Full Trust. My questions are:

1 - Does Aspnet Membership really require Full Trust to work?
2 - Is there a way to make work under Medium Trust, as the hosting service doesn't allow applications running under Full Trust?

Thanks anyway for your advice.

Comment: Answers are 1) No, it does not necessarily require full trust, 2)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx, I hope it will answer your query

Comment: That's right, it doesn't require full trust in some scenarios, but looks like it does if you are going to use Profiles feature, I was unable to force medium trust while using this function. My solution was to implement Profiles handling code by myself.